# Resolving Maven dependencies as an MsBuild Task

Tags: .net, maven, msbuild, msbuild-task

Is there any way to resolve dependencies from a Maven Repo without having to use the Maven for my entire build tool chain/project management? Ideally it would be nice to be able to run Maven to resolve dependencies as a MsBuild Task so that I can just do a fresh pull of the SVN, open up in VS and hit F5.

Also it would be really nice if it was compatible with the build server running MsBuild.

It would be really really awesome if I did not have to install Java and Maven just to get this to work.